# Android Studio -Issue when implementing google-service with existing app

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Im creating an app that has google maps as an activity, the app worked  before i implemented google maps into it , but the compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4' dependency in the build gradle seems to break it , my build gradle is as follows :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "jack.fyp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'

}
```

any help would be appreciated as ive looked all over and cant find a fix

This is error im receiving 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v35xz.png)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please paste your code and use the code tags instead of an image.

Comment: I will do that now